# Find the equations of two straight lines each of which is parallel to

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equations of two straight lines each of which is parallel to and at a distance of $\sqrt {5}$ from the line $x+2y-7=0$.

My Attempt:
The equation of any line parallel to $x+2y-7=0$ is
$x+2y+k=0$

The distance between these two lines is:
$$d=\dfrac {|k+7|}{\sqrt {5}}$$

Comment: And where exactly is your question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of any line parallel to $x+2y-7=0$ is
$x+2y+k=0$

The distance between these two lines is:
$$d=\dfrac {|k+7|}{\sqrt {5}}$$

Put $d=\sqrt {5}$
,

$$\sqrt {5}=\dfrac {|k+7|}{\sqrt {5}}$$

$5=|k+7|$

$k+7=5$ or $k+7=-5$

$k=-2$ or $k= -12$

Hence the equations of the two lines are $x+2y-2=0$
and $x+2y-12=0$